# Отмена действия выбора опции при select change

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

Есть обычный селект.
Как при изменении селекта, отменить действия по умолчанию ( не выбирать выбранный option, а выбирать его после выполнения условия ? ).

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // не отменяет
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.preventDefault()` с `<select>` не дружит, но можно это реализовать след. путем

```js
var lastValue = $('select').val(); // сохраняем первоначальное значение select
$('select').on('change', function(e){
     var value = $(this).val(),
         ok = false; // результат вашей проверки, нужно прописать вашу логику
     if(ok) { // тут уже проверка, если все ок, то все проходит хорошо, и дефолтное значение ставим новым
         lastValue = value;
     } else { // если не ок, вместо нового значения возвращаем старое
         $(this).val(lastValue);
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Правильнее будеть иметь исходный "нулевой" `option` (но не объязательно), используйте `selectedIndex`, решение такое:

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e){
if($(this).val()==1){
/*То что нам нужно*/
} else{
/*То что нам не нужно*/
$('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name">
  <option value="0">Выберите значение</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сохранить предыдущее значение по focus, а потом восстановить.

```
    let prevSelectVal;

    /* Сохранение первоначального значения */
    $('select').on('focus', function() {
        prevSelectVal = this.value;
    });


    /* Выбрано новое значение (срабатывает сразу после focus) */
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        if(!confirm('Вы уверены?')) {
            this.value = prevSelectVal; // возврат предыдущего значения
            return;
        }
        // действия с select'ом.
    });
```